# Have PermissionError when I run "poetry run" command

Tags: python, python-poetry

### Environment

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Python 3.7.3
- Poetry 1.0.8

### My Problem

I installed poetry to manage packages, and I tried it with following simple project,

```sh
.
└── myproject
    ├── README.rst
    ├── myproject
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── main.py
    ├── myproject.egg-info
    │   ├── PKG-INFO
    │   ├── SOURCES.txt
    │   ├── dependency_links.txt
    │   ├── requires.txt
    │   └── top_level.txt
    ├── poetry.lock
    ├── pyproject.toml
    └── tests
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_myproject.py
```

To run `main.py` I tried

```sh
$ poetry run myproject/main.py
```

But I had an error, which says,

```sh
[PermissionError]
[Errno 13] Permission denied
```

### What I tried

To run my code, I tried another way.

```
$ poetry shell
(myproject-x8XipcUE-py3.7)$ python myproject/main.py
```

I had no error...

What is the problem for my `poetry run` command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that `myproject/main.py` isn't an executable (doesn't have the 'x') permission. That's why you can run it with `python myproject/main.py`, but can't run it as the main exe. To fix it, run `chmod +x myproject/main.py`, and then try `poetry run` again.

Of course, you'll have to have a proper Shebang at the very top of `main.py`. Something like `#!/usr/bin/env python` (again - at the very beginning of the file).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried, but I had other error "[OSError] [Errno 8] Exec format error".

Answer (score 45):

Just for reference you can also do `poetry run python myproject/main.py`.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. adding +x to python script is not really secure.

Comment: This's the correct answer; the nature of these tools is different, and poetry is just managing deps on the other hand run command can't execute .py module without proper REPL. so it is required to execute the module by combining `poetry run` command and `python` which lets build the package with correct dependencies.